Local notification for a Game in UWP platform and developed by unity
I want to implement local notification system in unity and for UWP platform. Can You tell me your suggestions regarding this purpose?
I wanted to try OneSignal, but the support clarified that they don't support local notifications. I'll appreciate if you provide me the link to SDK and documentation as well.


I want to implement local notification system in unity and for UWP platform. Can You tell me your suggestions regarding this purpose?

If you want to send toast notification, you will need to install the Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications NuGet package version 7.0 or greater.
The following code is a simple example:
new ToastContentBuilder()
.AddArgument("action", "viewConversation")
.AddArgument("conversationId", 9813)
.AddText("Andrew sent you a picture")
.AddText("Check this out, The Enchantments in Washington!")
.Show();

For more details, depends on the language you use, you could check one of the following documents:
Send a local toast notification from a C# app(work for WPF, UWP, WinForms, console)
Send a local toast notification from C++ UWP apps
You could also go through the following documents about how to customize the content of the notification:
Toast content schema
App notification content
Update:

How to change the target version of the UWP app?

Please do it in the project properties.


Thank you it helped a lot. but I'm still having some problem. For using Show(), I need to change TFM (target framework). For that I should change it via its csproj. I couldn't find the csproj for my unity project. how can I change it. I have to change it to net6.0-windows10.0.17763.0 .

I'm not familiar with unity project so I can't tell where to change it in Unity. If you are opening your project in Visual Studio as a UWP project. You should be able to change it in by right click the project - go to properties. Then you could set the target version and min version. I've uploaded a screenshot about how to change it by updating my answer.
